# How do I get an access token using stravalib?

Tags: python

Using the sample code of stravalib I have worked on understanding how the program works what I have is as follows:

```
    from stravalib import Client

    code = request.args.get('code') # e.g.
    client = Client()
    access_token = client.exchange_code_for_token(client_id="Mas Rosenberg",
    client_secret="***********************************",
                                          code='code')

    client = Client(access_token)
    athlete = client.get_athlete()

    print("Hello, {}".format(athlete.firstname))
```

The 'code' with the # e.g. next to it, what should that be?

Comment: code = request.args.get('code') means that code will be the value assigned to the key "code" in the dictionary request.args. And are you sure that the call to access_token is correct?

Comment: I saw the docs and yes, your access_token call has a mistake in the code='code' it should be code=code as you are trying to pass the value you obtained

Comment: @Aquiles `code(from stravalib import Client
import requests
client = Client()
url = client.authorization_url(client_id=12032,
                               redirect_uri='http://127.0.0.1:5000/authorization')
code = requests.get(url)
access_token = client.exchange_code_for_token(client_id=12032,                                             client_secret="*****",
                                              code=code)
client = Client(access_token)
athlete = client.get_athlete()
print("Hello, {}".format(athlete.firstname))`

Comment: Sorry it isn't formatted, I'm new to this. Thanks so much for your help. The code above gets the following error:

Comment: File "/Users/samrosenberg/PycharmProjects/CyclingCard/Cyclist.py", line 14, in <module> code=code)
.
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad request [None]               The dot replaces more lines of information, if that would help, let me know.

Comment: are you actually using **** for the client_secret? I believe you need to change it for the client_secret of your account

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else had trouble with this I followed this slightly different tutorial:
[link here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2FPNb1XECGs) (so full credits to the guy!).
Here you first refresh the access token:

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from stravalib.client import Client
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()


auth_url ="https://www.strava.com/oauth/token"
payload = {
    'client_id' : CLIENT_ID,
    'client_secret' : CLIENT_SECRET,
    'refresh_token' : REFRESH_TOKEN,
    'grant_type' : "refresh_token",
    'f':'json'
}
print("Requesting the token...\n")
res = requests.post(auth_url,data=payload,verify=False)
print(res.json())
print()

access_token = res.json()['access_token']
expiry_ts = res.json()['expires_at']
print("New token will expire at: ",end='\t')
print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(expiry_ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

client = Client(access_token=access_token)
athlete = client.get_athlete() 
print(f'Hello {athlete.firstname} {athlete.lastname}')
```

The tokens CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REFRESH_TOKEN can be accessed once logged in from *https://www.strava.com/settings/api*

Comment: cool,  simple and used cool. thanks.